# iOS app asks for password every time it is launched

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm testing a new app on my device, and today, I started integrating the StoreKit for In-App Purchases.

The problem is that EVERY TIME I launch the app, it asks me for my sandbox account password. Here following, you'll find some details about the problem.

1. The very first time I launched the app, everything worked as expected. No problems while completing the in-app purchase (with my sandbox user - let's call it testuser1@t.com -).
2. Stopped the app, integrated a button "Restore purchases". Unfortunately, I forgot to add "finishTransaction" at completion (not sure if this could be the problem).
3. From now on, every time I launch the app, it keeps asking me for testuser1@t.com's password.

StoreKit starts doing it's stuff in a view which is NOT the rootView, so I excluded that I'm casting something wrong programmatically...

So, what I did AFTER?

1. Deleted app from device and reinstalled (after reboot)
2. Deleted sandbox user (and created a new one - let's say testuser2@t.com -). I successfully used the NEW account in order to get a new IAP.
3. Cleared settings on my device
4. Deleted IAP from iTunes Connect

The problem is still there. Keep in mind that the password asked is for testuser1@t.com (the very first test account!)

Comment: Go to Settings on the device and try signing in as testuser1 within the "ITunes & App Store" section. You may have to re-create testuser1 on iTunesConnect. Once you're signed in as testuser1, sign out.

Comment: @GlennRay that's impossible. iTunes Connect says that an Apple ID with that email already exists... However I logged in/out with my test user account but nothing changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Stopped the app, integrated a button "Restore purchases". Unfortunately, I forgot to add "finishTransaction" at completition (not sure if this could be the problem)

That is indeed the problem!

Store Kit will always ask you to re-authenticate if there are transactions left on the queue. To get rid of those transactions, just call:

```
for transaction in SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().transactions {
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
}
```